# Why wasn't Naruto able to sense Black Zetsu?

Tags: naruto

If Black Zetsu was commanded to be with  Obito while Madara was fighting the 5 kages,

How come, Naruto was not able to sense Black Zetsu in his Kyuubi mode while fighting with Obito??

Comment: it's never stated, that naruto didn't sense BZ. your assumptions are wrong. also most of this "i sense evil" is actually anime filler, meaning non-canonical. there is bound to be a loophole ;)

Comment: I think Naruto's ability to sense evil is not a filler only since it plays a big part during the war to battle White Zetsu's.

Comment: right. and after that it is never even mentioned again.... certainly not filler.. the writers just needed something to get the white Zetsus off the board, and some new special power for naruto was just the right thing for that. still it's never stated naruto **didn't** sense BZ

Comment: Naruto's ability to sense evil is NOT a filler, because Naruto sensed kisame using his evil sensing powers and also during the war the alliance relied on his evil sensing powers heavily. One reason why Naruto did not (rather than could not) sense BZ is beacause he was more worried about fighiting Obito who himself was a "big" evil to worry about. Remember Naruto doesn't think with his brains.. and isn't the best analyser.. :P

Comment: Or, the BZ simply did not have any evil intentions at that time. All he was supposed to do was, have an eye on Obito. Why should the BZ even think of going into the offensive mode as Obito was okay by himself till then? Also, I really doubt if there can be a definitive answer for this, as nothing has been spoken about this in the Manga, as of now.

Answer (score 1):

One might be able to look at it from the philosophical point of view that there was no evil to sense.

The rest of this answer may include spoilers

> Black Zetsu is essentially Kaguya's will incarnate. That being said, Kaguya's goals were not inherently evil. Technically, her goal was peace. While it may have been a peace forced upon the entire world, in a manner they did not agree with, in her mind, it was still an act of good. It's true that she did want the power of her chakra back from all those it had been sewn into throughout the centuries. Even still, it is difficult for mere mortals to understand what drives a being that could be consider god-like. Good and Evil being matters of perception, maybe Kaguya truly believed in the good of her actions. Of course, this is all speculation, but one has to wonder, I mean when Kaguya initially thought that Naruto and Sasuke were Hagoromo and Hamura, she wept, so she can't be all bad.
>
>  All that considered, and Black Zetsu being an extension of Kaguya himself, maybe the whole "sensing evil" didn't work because there was no evil intent. But this all hinges on the philosophy of good and evil, and deciding if there is a difference between knowing something is evil and not caring, or not believing something is evil because of the eventual good, it will do.

Answer (score 0):

As we now know Black Zetsu had the will of Kaguya in him. Just as Naruto wasn't able to sense the Ten Tails (episode 363 of the anime) , Kaguya's powers are even greater than the Ten Tails - she stopped the Infinite Tsukuyomi easily. So sensing Kaguya (or Black Zetsu) is out of the question.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. Naruto couldn't sense the Juubi with Kurama's chakra because in that mode he can sense negative emotions (hate, sadness, anger), and the Juubi doesn't have emotions. Black Zetsu and Kaguya are not the same as that.

Answer (score 0):

I think Naruto could sense BZ evil intent, but maybe not his physical body because the Zetsu army and BZ are as close to nature as beings can be. White Zetsu was able to sneak into the Kage summit ffs, even with the Raikage's senser-nin (C) with him. The Zetsu's are all made from the Juubi/Tree, the origins of chakra so I'm assuming they'd be overlooked even if Naruto was in Sage mode because they're purely artificial/organic humanoids.